# Extjs Tag fields in grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a grid which has tag columns as follow:

```
    Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'tagStore',
            fields:[ 'id', 'name'],
            data: [
                { id: '123', name: 'cartoon'},
                { id: '124', name: 'animation'},
                { id: '125', name: 'comedy'},
                { id: '126', name: 'action'}
                ]

        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'movieStore',
            fields:[ 'name', 'tags'],
            data: [
                { name: 'Simpsons', tags: '123,124'},
                { name: 'Zootopia', tags: '123,124,125' },
                { name: 'The Godfather', tags: '126' },
                { name: 'La La Land', tags: '123' }
                ]

        });


        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Movies',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('movieStore'),
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name', flex: 2,dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Tags', flex: 3,dataIndex: 'tags'}
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

    }
});
```

Sencha fiddle link is https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1u84

I want to change grid so that it will be able to edit tags column using [tagfield](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html) in such a manner that will show name instead of id but when you update the grid it will send id instead of tags name.

Comment: It looks like the fiddle is already OK ?

Comment: Yup, I figured out from documentation and fiddling. I will update this post with answer, which might help someone else. Thank you for looking into it.